# Positioning UIViewControllers in UIScrollView side by side

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I've got a main View Controller that has a subview of UIScrollView and another 2 UIViewControllers (each with nibs UIView and buttons). The UIViewControllers' UIView are added into UIScrollView using addSubView method. And I'd like to put both UIViewControllers side by side.

I've got the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
[self scrollView].pagingEnabled = YES;
[self scrollView].contentSize = CGSizeMake(768 * 2, 1024);
[[self scrollView] setDelegate:self];

CGRect frame1;
frame1.origin.x = 0;
frame1.origin.y = 0;
frame1.size = CGSizeMake(768, 1024);

// Model one
oneView = [[OneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OneViewController" bundle:nil];
//oneView.view.frame = frame1;
[self.scrollView addSubview:oneView.view];
oneView.view.frame = frame1;

// Model two

CGRect frame2;
frame2.origin.x = 768;
frame2.origin.y = 0;
frame2.size = CGSizeMake(768, 1024);

twoView = [[TwoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwoViewController" bundle:nil];
//twoView.view.frame = frame2;
[self.scrollView addSubview:twoView.view];
twoView.view.frame = frame2;
```

Why does oneView and twoView inside UIScrollView are in the same place when I've set their frame.origin.x? twoView seems to be on top of oneView where it should be side by side? Any idea where I am doing it wrong? Thanks!

**Update**: Here's my full project code on github: http://bit.ly/PLe1Le

Comment: What would be wrong with just saying `frame.origin.x = 768;`

Comment: I was testing with more than 2 UIViewControllers as subviews of UIScrollView and when the code doesn't work, I decided to narrow down and left the x as it is. I'll changed above code to the one you specify so that it's clearer.

Comment: FYI you didn't check in your Xcode project file into the repository.

Comment: Oops, updated the repository. It has Xcode project file now.

Comment: Thanks. What's going on is similar to as torrey.lyons' answer below, I think. If the height of the content views reaches or exceeds 1024 pixels it happens, if you don't let them get that tall it doesn't. I have no idea why though - it doesn't appear actually correlated with anything on the content size. While I can't yet give you an answer as to why it's happening I can give you an answer with code that fixes the problem if you think that's sufficient for the bounty.

Comment: Yes please. I am ready to award the bounty to code fixes. Perhaps when other experts chime in their more detailed explanation, I'll put their answer as accepted answers. :)

Comment: Never mind. Borrowing some code from other post, I think I got it fixed. Please see my own reply below. Thanks for the tip, Carl! :)

Comment: Shoot, SO stopped notifying me I had a new reply! Sorry! Well I think I finally figured out the why. Give me a few minutes to test a few more things and I'll see if I can't give an answer.

Comment: Never mind, Carl. I got it fixed. Please see my answer below. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15832/discussion-between-eddy-and-carl-veazey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this started happening is that any `UIView` instance that is the value of a `UIViewController`'s `view` property will sometimes get a message to resize its view to that of its superviews.

Specifically, the undocumented method `viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:` will be called when a view controller's `view` is added to a window, as is happening at application launch in this instance. At this time, if the view controller's `view` instance is the size of the main window or larger, it will be resized to the size of its superview.

The original code took the two views that were loaded from the the .xibs and sized them to 768 * 1024, which is the size of the window. This happens **before** `-makeKeyAndVisible` is called on the window, which ends up triggering the resize. I used KVO in the app delegate to watch the frames get resized; here is a stack trace at the time of resize:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x000030f9 scroller`-[ViewController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 105 at ViewController.m:71, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000030f9 scroller`-[ViewController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 105 at ViewController.m:71
    frame #1: 0x0093ad91 Foundation`NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 345
    frame #2: 0x0093a895 Foundation`NSKeyValueDidChange + 438
    frame #3: 0x0092033e Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 131
    frame #4: 0x009cdcb4 Foundation`_NSSetRectValueAndNotify + 187
    frame #5: 0x000e1786 UIKit`-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:] + 657
    frame #6: 0x0005310c UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1040
    frame #7: 0x00052edb UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 479
    frame #8: 0x0005d5ab UIKit`-[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 65
    frame #9: 0x00052edb UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 479
    frame #10: 0x0004f692 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 158
    frame #11: 0x0005446f UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1633
    frame #12: 0x0004e14b UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    frame #13: 0x0003d550 UIKit`-[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 380
    frame #14: 0x0003d670 UIKit`-[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 280
    frame #15: 0x0003d836 UIKit`-[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    frame #16: 0x0004472a UIKit`-[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 35
    frame #17: 0x00002575 scroller`-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 661 at AppDelegate.m:21
    frame #18: 0x00015386 UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1292
    frame #19: 0x00016274 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 524
    frame #20: 0x00025183 UIKit`-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1027
    frame #21: 0x00025c38 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
    frame #22: 0x00019634 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196
    frame #23: 0x0139eef5 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 1274
    frame #24: 0x01488195 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    frame #25: 0x013ecff2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    frame #26: 0x013eb8da CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2218
    frame #27: 0x013ead84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    frame #28: 0x013eac9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #29: 0x00015c65 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 576
    frame #30: 0x00017626 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1163
    frame #31: 0x000022ad scroller`main + 141 at main.m:16
```

We can verify that this happens because the content views are a `UIViewController` 's view instance by instantiating a view and adding it the scroll view at the same time. I added the following code to the end of `ViewController` 's `viewDidLoad` implementation:

```
CGRect frame3 = frame2;
frame3.origin.x = 768.0f * 2.0f;
UIView *thirdView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame3];
[thirdView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.scrollView addSubview:thirdView];
```

As well as changing the line assigning content size to:

```
[self scrollView].contentSize = CGSizeMake(768 * 3, 1024);
```

This view does not get its frame set during `makeKeyAndVisible` and is in the correct place.

To work around the issue, I'd recommend setting up the view hierarchy after the window has `-makeKeyAndVisible` called, possibly in a viewWillAppear (Not sure if that will have the same issue) or by otherwise structuring your code to delay the laying out of the scroll view. Alternatively, re-set the frames at a later time as an explicit undoing of this bug.

I hope this helps explain what was happening and that the evidence I provide is clear and credible; it seems you already have a fix for your particular case but hopefully this answer stands as a general solution to frame misbehavior when `UIViewController`'s have their views laid out inside scroll views.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Carl! The bounty will be awarded in 1 hours (system restriction). :)

Comment: Thanks so much Eddy I really appreciate that. Let me know if I can help you out in any other way or clarify this further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the subviews to the scroll view first, then setting their location? I found in a different situation I was trying to add information to a view before displaying it in a scroll view, only for the text fields to be blank. Views have a strange quirk in where values may return to their default value when being displayed.

Comment: I've tried setting their location both before and after adding the UIViewControllers to the UIScrollView. Please see my update above with github link. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that your two views are too large *vertically* to fit in the content size of your scroll view. Your scroll view's content is only (768 * 2) x 900. You are sizing both of your subviews to be 768 x 1024. Since they don't fit anyway, the scroll view probably just gives us and puts them both at the origin. Change your second line to:

```
[self scrollView].contentSize = CGSizeMake(768 * 2, 1024);
```

Comment: I edited the *height* of the UIViewController to 900 to see if I can see the overlap or something from the Simulator. But couldn't find anything so I reverted it back to 1024. I've updated my code above and  also added a github link to my source code.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing some code from this post : [UIScrollView adding UIViewController as a sub view? with UIPageControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333784/uiscrollview-adding-uiviewcontroller-as-a-sub-view-with-uipagecontrol?rq=1), I think I got it fixed by using self.scrollView.frame.size.width instead of using a fixed value of 768.

```
[self scrollView].pagingEnabled = YES;
[self scrollView].contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
[[self scrollView] setDelegate:self];

CGRect frame1;
frame1.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 0;
frame1.origin.y = 0;
frame1.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

// Model one
oneView = [[OneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OneViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.scrollView addSubview:oneView.view];
oneView.view.frame = frame1;

// Model two
CGRect frame2;
frame2.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 1;
frame2.origin.y = 0;
frame2.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

twoView = [[TwoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwoViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.scrollView addSubview:twoView.view];
twoView.view.frame = frame2;
```

Also, I've updated my repository so that you can test the project as a whole. Here's the link again : http://bit.ly/PLe1Le  :)